# Powershell dll information

Tags: windows, dll, powershell

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с задачей, и споткнулся на следующем моменте.

Имеется: powershell (и только он).

Требуется: узнать инфу в dll'ке, подгруженную в конкретный процесс.

Сталкивался кто с подобным?

Comment: Боюсь, понадобятся исходники [ListDLLs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) или [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Если там дотнет, можно попробовать в лоб перенести, через `Add-Type`, а если плюсы, проще скачать/перенести и вызвать.

Comment: Хотелось бы конечно использовать только PS без всяких сторонних приложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, нужно получить список DLL, загруженных в процесс и получить информацию об этих DLL. Вот пример кода:

```
$dlls = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq "Process.Name" } | Select -ExpandProperty Modules
$dlls | ForEach-Object {
    $dll = Get-Item -Path $_.FileName
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        'FileName' = $($dll.Name)
        'Version' = $($dll.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
        'Modified' = $($dll.LastWriteTime)
    } 
} | Format-Table FileName,Version,Modified -AutoSize
```

Если неправильно понял вопрос, то уточните, пожалуйста, что именно нужно узнать.

Источники:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041062/retrieving-dll-path-of-a-running-process
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1bd5bf20-29ab-4edf-bb17-9a58db1dc3f1/how-to-get-dll-details-using-powershell-script

Comment: Все верно.
Спасибо.